# Gradle get dependency definitions from another build file

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

In gradle is it possible to get dependencies for a build from another build file ?

Example, Imagine `project-1` has `project1/build.gradle`, How do I get the dependencies of the same in `project-2` from `project2/build.gradle` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cou could put your dependencies in an external file, e.g. 'dependencies.gradle' and import it like this:

```
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
```